# Error when open secondViewcontroller / segue (...whose view is not in the window hierarchy!)

Tags: xcode, ios7, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have 2 Viewcontroller connected with a one segue: "open2" / Modal
note:(In the first Viewcontroller I have animation, timer, etc running when I call to the second viewcontroller...)

From the first viewcontroller a call one action to open the secondvoewcontroller: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"open2" sender:self];
The second Viewcontroller has been open but in the console message appear this error:

""" Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"""

I checked and tested many tutorials but at the moment not solve the problem...

Please can you help me ! Thanks in advance !

Edit.